# Server exiting after upgrading to Rails 5.0.0.rc1 from rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to upgrade my app's rails version from 4.2.6 to 5 but I am stuck with the following error.

```
suramai@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/converse (rails5update) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.0.rc1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:79:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table, :foreign_type, :index_errors (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:77:in `each_key'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:77:in `assert_valid_keys'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:78:in `validate_options'
```

Changed the scope

```
  #default_scope -> { order: 'created_at DESC' }
  scope :created_at, ->  { order('created_at DESC') }
```

Added gem files

```
gem "responders"
```

Created

```
models/application_record.rb

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Ensured that all models inherit from this new class, for example:

```
models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  [...]
end
```

Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using mailboxes add it as (with the github source) in order to get the master version of mailboxer and this fixed the issue for me

gem 'mailboxer', github: 'mailboxer/mailboxer'

Comment: Thank you @salma-gooma, I have added a [new issue on mailboxer](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/427) that references this answer, asking to better document the issue...